# How is symfony normalizer instantiated?

Tags: symfony

I'm looking at a symfony project that is declaring a custom normalizer. It has an optional argument in the constructor which is getting ignored.

```
public function __construct(SomeInterface $firstArg, $secondArg = false)
{
    //$secondArg is always false
}
```

There is some yml config:

```
Path/To/Custom/Normalizer:
    arguments:
        $secondArg: true
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

I'm trying to understand what is instantiating this class, and why is the second argument always false, despite the fact that the yml config defines it as true.

Is the normalizer instantiated using the yml config, or does symfony instantiate these using some other mechanism?

More info:
if i make the second constructor arg mandatory, then the container wont compile. complaining that it can't autowire the second arg and that i must configure its value explicitly. Which is what i am trying to do.

Comment: Are you following: https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html ? It almost seems like you are new'ing your normalizer which won't get you very far at all.

Comment: @Cerad I didn't write this class, but yes it looks like the author has followed that guide. It is implementing the NormalizerInterface. The service has been registered and tagged. It works, but second arg is always true.

Comment: I actually think this has nothing to do with the fact it's a normalizer. It's some config issue. Maybe I should ask a more generic question about how to debug the container when it's ignoring my defined arguments

Comment: Okay.  But quite a few developers configure a service and then try to use new Service() to instantiate one thinking that the new operator somehow know about the container.  Good luck.

Comment: @Cerad. The problem was the order in which the bundles are defined in AppKernel.php. We seem to keep needing to swap them round every now and then to solve issues. I think our real problem is we have bundles that depend upon each other, creating a dependency loop. Now wer're fighting over which one should be defined first. Thanks for your help. I'll probably delete this question because I don't think it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring of symfony doesn't know how to autowire scalar parameters type.

Your manual configuration will never be execute if you enable autowiring for this service.. So the container tries to create new instance of your service but he doesn't know how to instantiate the boolean parameters.

What you can to is to exclude this service from the autowiring

It is a bad idea and can become quickly a very big headache to have different default value on constructor and the service configuration itself.

Comment: It does feel like my config is not being considered. However, it makes no difference if autowiring is set to true or false. Changing the order the bundles are defined in AppKernel.php, seems to have an effect. If I swap the order around and clear the cache (twice, I know it's weird) then things start to work and I can control the second arg.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the bundles are loaded, defined in AppKernel.php makes a difference to the configuration.

Even though there does not seem to be any other configuration of this class in any other bundle.